# Failed to convert Tensorflow .pd to json

Tags: tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

Trying to convert the saved model to json for tensorflow js. Followed the example from https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter

Version:
tensorflowjs 1.2.9

Dependency versions:
  keras 2.2.4-tf
  tensorflow 1.14.0

Ran this cmd:

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model --output_format=tfjs_graph_model --signature_name=serving_default --saved_model_tags=serve /saved_model  /web_model
```

Having this error message while running the code:

```
F .\tensorflow/core/grappler/graph_view.h:332] Check failed: st.ok() Non unique node name detected: SecondStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Mixed_5c/Branch_2/Conv2d_0c_3x3/weights
```

Comment: Can you describe the version of tfjs-converter and the name of the model you tried to convert?

Comment: Hi Kai Sasaki, here are the details:

tensorflowjs 1.2.9

Dependency versions:
  keras 2.2.4-tf
  tensorflow 1.14.0

And the model i am trying to convert is faster rcnn inception v2 coco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the converter only works on Google Colab without any issue. Thanks everyone for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the latest converter version 1.3.1.1
I believe the issue has been fixed. 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2055

Comment: I did change to the latest version but still facing the same issue